# How to properly make OPEN and SAVE function with Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a simple shopping list application.
Whenever I try to save the content from the listbox `shopping_list` it saves as a tuple `('.., .., ...,')` in the `.txt` file the function creates.

When I use the `open` button, the `listbox` displays the text as a `tuple`.

Example:

If in the entry field I write something like `pizza` and add it to the `listbox` and save it. When I try to open the same file into the `listbox`, the `listbox` now displays: `('pizza')`. How can I get the listbox to display only `pizza`?

The code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


def add_item():
    '''
        This function takes the input from the entry field
        and places the item in a shopping list.

    :return: Adds to list
    '''

    if len(user_input.get()) == 0: # Checks if user typed into the entry field.
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "No keys were detected from the Entry field") # Send warning for no input.

    # Else statement for adding the user input to shopping list.
    else:
        shopping_list.insert(END, user_input.get())
        user_input.delete(0, END)  # Deletes whatever the user wrote in the entry box after button is clicked.


def remove_item():
    '''
        This function deletes the selected items when REMOVE button is clicked
    '''
    try:
        selected = shopping_list.curselection()
        for item in selected[::-1]:  # Fetches all selected items from shopping list
            shopping_list.delete(item)


    # Make a warning if the shopping list is empty or items are not selected when REMOVE button is clicked.
    except TclError:
        messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "The shopping list is either empty \nor you didn't select an item")


def open_list():
    '''
        This function opens an existing shopping list that was previously saved.
    :return: Opens older saved files.
    '''
    root.file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="./", title="Select a file",
                                           filetypes=(("Txt files", "*.txt"), ("All files", "*,*")))

    with open(root.file, "r") as file:
        data_content = file.read()
        shopping_list.delete(0, END)
        shopping_list.insert(END, data_content)


def save_file():
    '''
        This function saves the whole shopping list and writes the content to the "shopping_list.txt" file.
    :return: None
    '''
    text_file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt")
    try:
        with open(text_file, "w") as file:
            file.write(str(shopping_list.get(0, END)))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        messagebox.showinfo("Alert", "No file was saved")

# backup eldre løsning:
"""
def save_file():
    '''
        This function saves the whole shopping list and writes the content to the "shopping_list.txt" file.
    :return: None
    '''
    root.filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename()
    with open("shopping_list.txt", "w") as f:
        for i in shopping_list.get(0, END):
            f.write(i+"\n")

"""



# Root files
root = Tk()
root.title("Skoleoppgave OBLIG 5")
root.iconbitmap('favicon.icns')
root.geometry("500x500")
root.resizable(0, 0)


# TODO: Entry  widget  ENTRY  1
# Creating an Entry widget so user can add items to shopping-list.
user_input = Entry(root, relief=SUNKEN)
user_input.pack()
user_input.place(x=250, y=20, anchor=N)


# Todo: Buttons widget ADD ITEM 2
# Make a Button-widget that adds the user input from entry field to the shopping list.
add_entry = Button(root, text="ADD ITEM", command=add_item, padx=10, pady=5)
add_entry.pack()
add_entry.place(x=158, y=57)



# Todo: Listbox  widget 4
# Creating Listbox for shopping list items
shopping_list = Listbox(root, selectmode=EXTENDED)
shopping_list.pack()
shopping_list.place(x=160, y=100)

"""
# Opens last saved shopping list when program starts.
try:
    read = open("shopping_list.txt","r")
    list_file = read.readlines()
    read.close()
    for data in list_file:
        shopping_list.insert(0, END, data)
except FileNotFoundError:
    read = open("shopping_list.txt","w")
"""


# Todo: Buttons widget REMOVE 3
# Make a Button-widget that deletes the selected item from shopping list
remove_entry = Button(root, text="REMOVE", command=remove_item, padx=10, pady=5)
remove_entry.pack()
remove_entry.place(x=160, y=285)


# Todo: Buttons widget OPEN 5
# Make a Button-widget that deletes the selected item from shopping list
open_file = Button(root, text="OPEN", command=open_list, padx=10, pady=5)
open_file.pack()
open_file.place(x=160, y=285)

# Todo: Buttons widget SAVE 6
# Make a Button-widget that deletes the selected item from shopping list
save_file = Button(root, text="SAVE", command=save_file, padx=10, pady=5)
save_file.pack()
save_file.place(x=282, y=57)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Since Tkinter's Listbox `get` method returns a Tuple (see [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_listbox.htm)), it's no surprise that it's being written that way. It just means that you have you parse the value as a tuple when loading the file. Or write out each item on its own line or something, then when reading it back, split on each new line. Lots of ways to solve the issue, you just have to have the correct assumptions when reading in the file's data, which you currently don't (i.e. passing in the whole tuple as a string rather than parsing out each item from it).

Comment: yeah thanks for the answer, but that is the thought I came up with before posting. but practical I couldn't do it. I searched for ways to split the tuple when opening the file from the application. but I can't seem to figure it out. you wrote PARSE? I don't know what that means. like I said, im completely new to this.  guess ill just have to google more. thanks for the reply.

Comment: You get a tuple out via `get`, so you can write it out as not a tuple, but as a list of strings with a newline, comma or whatever in between each one. Then you just have to do the reverse when reading the data from the file. If you're hung up on such a basic concept though, then yeah, I think you need to do a lot more googling and following of tutorials (specifically file input/output).

Comment: Thanks again for the answer Davis. Im currently 2 months into my degree in computer science, so yeah, I do need to learn more. that's basically what im trying to do right now. Learn..

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are trying to put a string into a method that is asking for a tuple, that will give an error.

so one way is that you add functionality both in reading and writing to write a data format to the file that you control yourself. tip is trying to replicate one to one what you see in the listbox to the textfile. It looks like your "eldre losning" will put one item per line. So the thing is to read the file so that you get a list of strings where every row becomes an item in the list. Hint... `.split` on strings works good for that.

Or, just deal with the string you already have in the file.
One way to do that is to add/modify the following.

```
from ast import literal_eval # added import for safe evals

# modified open
with open(root.file, "rt") as file:
    data_content = literal_eval(file.read())
    shopping_list.delete(0, END)
    shopping_list.insert(END, *data_content)
```

Side note #1, you don't need `.pack()` if you use `.place`.
Side note #2, next time around, mention that you are doing homework upfront.
Side note #3, if you use what's in this answer - you might have to do some reading before you can explain why it could be done like this to be believed that you came up with it yourself :-)

Good luck with your studies and learning.

Comment: Hello again, @ahed87 ! Just wanted to follow up your answer and tell you I solved the problem, finally after many hours. I ended up with a different method. I changed the method on how the function writes to the file when it is saved. I used a For loop to add a comma to every objekt. and in that way when I load a list with the open function, it creates now a list for every objekt with an COMMA behind it. So now it finally works, and I didn't need to copy your solution. Thanks for the reply!!